# how can i show progress bar while sending an email in java

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

hii every one
I want to show progress bar 
while my program sends email

how can i do it?

Comment: What UI technology are you using (Swing, SWT, GWT...)?

Comment: what API do you use to send mail?

Answer (score 1):

Display a simple gif image with hourglass or striped loading bar or something similar. Since this will be a single step operation you can't actually tell the user N % complete. Add a callback with timeout to verify the success of the operation. How you display the image depends on what technology you are using.

Comment: Not necessarily a single step (connect to server, authenticate, send message). Thunderbird shows a progress bar for this. At least with longish attachments, it actually makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Swing's [JProgressBar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) is probably your best bet for an applet.

It has a mode for when you don't know how long an operation will take.

For JavaMail you can listen to the transport system (probably com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport) with a TransportListener which will tell you when each message has been sent at least, so you can do progress for multiple recipients.

Comment: Up with the lid. Javamail is open source.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put together two classes, [JProgressBar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) for the UI, and [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for the background thread. From your comments, it looks like you first need to be looking at a [SwingWorker tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html).

Answer (score 0):

depending on native/webapp, single email/multiple emails, solutions might be slightly different.

e.g webapp+single email, consider a animated gif, while you do send the email in another iframe.

e.g. webapp+multiple email, a progress bar can continuously display the percentage done, based on a number of sent emails/total emails, after each email get sent.

Comment: sry i didnt understand .. can u explain me in detail